# "<identifier> expected" compilation error in Java

Tags: java, identifier

I get "`<identifier> expected`" error on this line....

```
  private static String getReducedISBN(char 'x') {
```

...of this code....

```
public class CheckISBN7 {

//private static String originalISBN;  // class variable

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Prompt the user to enter an ISBN
    SimpleIO.prompt("Enter ISBN: ");
    String originalISBN = SimpleIO.readLine();

    // Get the ISBN number without the dashes
    String reducedISBN = getReducedISBN('-');

    // Get the computed check digit
    int computedCheckDigit = getCheckDigit(reducedISBN);

    // Display check digit entered by the user
    System.out.println("Check digit entered: " + originalISBN.charAt(12));

    // Display computed check digit
    System.out.println("Check digit computed: " + computedCheckDigit);
}

private static String getReducedISBN(char 'x') {
    SimpleIO.prompt("Enter ISBN: ");
    String originalISBN = SimpleIO.readLine();
    int dashPos1 = originalISBN.indexOf("x");
    int dashPos2 = originalISBN.indexOf("x", dashPos1 + 1);
    String reducedISBN = originalISBN.substring(0, dashPos1) +
            originalISBN.substring(dashPos1 + 1, dashPos2) +
            originalISBN.substring(dashPos2 + 1, 11);
    return reducedISBN;
}

private static int getCheckDigit(String reducedISBNParameter) {
    int total = 0;
    final String digits = "0123456789X";
    for(int i = 0, j = 10; i <= 8; i++, j++) {
        total += j *
                (Integer.parseInt(reducedISBNParameter.substring(i, i + 1)));
    }
    int checkDigit = 10 - ((total - 1) % 11);
    int computedCheckDigit = digits.charAt(checkDigit);
    return computedCheckDigit;
    }
}
```

Can't really figure out the problem , any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm, the error message is "<identifier> expected", not just "expected"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'x'` is not an indentifier (variable or whatever), it is a literal character. Likewise "x" is a literal string. Replace `char 'x'` with `Character x` and `"x"` with `x.toString()` to get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to pass the char value `'x'` in your method signature, which isn't valid syntax:

```
private static String getReducedISBN(char 'x') {
```

Did you mean to use `x` as a variable name?

```
private static String getReducedISBN(char x) {
```

As well as here, since I assume you're trying to find the index of whatever you pass as the separator character instead of the string `"x"`:

```
int dashPos1 = originalISBN.indexOf(x);
int dashPos2 = originalISBN.indexOf(x, dashPos1 + 1);
```

Comment: Note: `indexOf` will expect a `String` rather than a `char`.

Comment: Yes, that did it.Thank you very much, BoltClock. Now, however, I am getting a 'No Class Definition Found' runtime error. There are no longer any compilation errors. I am using the NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Which class does it say it can't find a definition for?

Comment: @user268396: Good call. Would a `toString()` call be necessary though? I've been rusty on my Java.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: checkdigit7/Main

Comment: @MassStrike: Your class is called `CheckISBN7`, if that helps. Check the name of your .java file, is it called checkdigit7.java?

Comment: Yes, the .java file is called CheckISBN7.java

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I suppose it's something particular to netbeans. I had to go into project properties and change checkisbn7.Main to checkisbn7.CheckISBN7. Thanks BoltClock and User forr all your help.

Comment: No problem. Remember to mark each best answer to your questions as accepted using the checkmark at the left.